# Drawing lines on an interactive column chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I've been using the chart API to draw a cross sectional profile of a landmass, using a slightly modified version of the chart example shown [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-paths.html).

however, I now need to draw a line of sight between the two end points, as well as a Fresnel(1) zone between the two. can this be done through the interactive chart API? or is there a better way to get this done?

also, I would like to 'select' the first and last entries to display their elevation, however my code doesn't appear to do anything:

```
Chart.setSelection([{row:0,column:null},{row:Results.length - 1, column:null}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding some other problems with the visualization API, I just gave up and did the whole thing using Raphael instead, works way better :D

EDIT: didn't know you couldn't answer your own posts within two days :| kinda of annoying since I've spent like a week straight trying to fandangle the bleeding chart -.-